# Show that $d\omega=(-1)^{n-1} (divX)dx_1 \wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

> Let, $X = (X_1,\dots,X_n): D \subset \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ vectr field on a domain $D$. Define $divX := \sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{\partial X_i}{\partial x_i}}$.
>    Define an $(n-1)$ form $\omega$ on $D$ by,$$\omega_p(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}):= det[v_1|\dots|v_{n-1}|X_p] , \forall p \in D, v_1,\dots v_{n-1} \in \Bbb R^n$$
>   Show that $d\omega=(-1)^{n-1} (divX)dx_1 \wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$

My attempt:

I know how to compute the exterior derivative of a form when it is of the form :$$\omega = \sum_{I}{a_I dx_I}$$ i.e. to find,$$d\omega=\sum_{I}{da_I \wedge dx_I}$$. But I am unable to recognize the given form in that form.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Is $\omega(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}):= det[v_1|\dots|v_{n-1}|X]$ ? and is it rather  $d\omega=(-1)^{n-1} (divX)dv_1 \wedge\dots\wedge dv_n$ ?

Comment: @NPE No, I've written whatever is in the exercises.

Comment: It must have something to do with $dw_p(v_1,...,v_{n-1})=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n d(X_p)_j det[v_k, k\neq j] = (-1)^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial (X_p)_j}{\partial x_i} dx_i det[v_k, k\neq j]$

Comment: @NPE would you please consider writing an answer?

Comment: Sorry the link between $dx_1\wedge…\wedge dx_n$ and $\sum_j dx_i det[v_k k\neq j]$ is too far fetch. Only trying to help, not answer